# java.lang.Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: java, opencv, hadoop, javacv

While executing my Hadoop application, I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/javacpp5024882630141562/libjniopencv_core.so: libopencv_core.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:399)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/javacpp5024882630141562/libjniopencv_core.so: libopencv_core.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1843)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1061)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:422)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:372)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:319)
        at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:338)
        at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:338)
        at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
        at com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber.start(OpenCVFrameGrabber.java:169)
        at HFD.videoprocessing.utils.VideoRecordReader.initialize(VideoRecordReader.java:58)
        at HFD.videoprocessing.utils.VideoInputFormat.createRecordReader(VideoInputFormat.java:30)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:698)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:333)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you provide the code ?

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-how-to-handle-unsatisfied-link-error/

Comment: An UnsatisfiedLinkError, at least in my experience, is always a missing native. In your case libopencv_core.so.2.3

Comment: Yeah that I know. The problem is I have no idea about from where to get this shared library. I have included javacv-linux-x86_64.jar in my project. In this jar there is a shared file with same name but without extension means I have libopencv_core.so instead of libopencv_core.so.2.3.

Comment: It means that libopencv_core.so.2.3 is not in the class path or that libopencv_core.so.2.3 depends on another shared library not available for the program ... did you tried ldd /path/to/your/lib.so ?

Comment: I just tried that. Here are the results: ldd /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff34cec000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa478fd2000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa478db5000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa478bac000)
        libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007fa47892d000)

Comment: export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/javacv.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/javacpp.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/javacv-linux-x86.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/javacv-linux-x86_64.jar
export LIBJARS=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/javacv.jar,/usr/local/hadoop/lib/javacpp.jar,/usr/local/hadoop/lib/javacv-linux-x86.jar,/usr/local/hadoop/lib/javacv-linux-x86_64.jar

Comment: I added the above mentioned commands and after that this libopencv_core.so.2.3 error came out.

Comment: I found one thread related to same problem but I have no idea what solution they suggested. Here is the link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javacv/4Cac4LoT3-M

Answer (score 2):

try the following :
1) run `sudo ldconfig` and check if that works.

if above does not works

2) open the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf` and insert the following in it
`/usr/local/opencv/`

then type: `sudo ldconfig`

if you can't find `opencv.conf` try `locate opencv.conf` to find it in your system